# Curve 25519 (X25519, Ed25519) Convert coordinates between Montgomery curve and twisted Edwards curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, ed25519, x25519

I have some misunderstanding about EdDSA conversion coordinates between Montgomery curve and twisted Edwards curve. In https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748 I see that a base point for Curve25519 is

Montgomery curve:

```
U(P)  9
V(P)  14781619447589544791020593568409986887264606134616475288964881837755586237401
```

Twisted Edwards curve:

```
X(P)  15112221349535400772501151409588531511454012693041857206046113283949847762202
Y(P)  46316835694926478169428394003475163141307993866256225615783033603165251855960
```

and then I see

```
The birational maps are:
```

$(u, v) = \frac{1+y}{1-y}, \sqrt{-486664}*\frac{u}{x}$

$(x, y) = \sqrt{-486664}*\frac{u}{v}, \frac{u-1}{u+1}$

But if we try convert $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ or $(u,v)$ to $(x,y)$ by using these formulas, we will not get correct answers. For example convert y-coordinate to u-coordinate:

```
(1+46316835694926478169428394003475163141307993866256225615783033603165251855960)/(1-46316835694926478169428394003475163141307993866256225615783033603165251855960)
```

result will not be equal to

```
14781619447589544791020593568409986887264606134616475288964881837755586237401
```

How can I convert coordinates between Montgomery curve and twisted Edwards curve correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The formulas actually work.
You just have to keep in mind to make computation in the field of intergers modulo $2^{255}-19$ and that there are actually **two** square roots, you need to use the right one if you want to have the expected result.

You can test the following SAGE code

```
gf=GF(2^255-19)
X_P = gf(15112221349535400772501151409588531511454012693041857206046113283949847762202)
Y_P = gf(46316835694926478169428394003475163141307993866256225615783033603165251855960)
u = (1+Y_P)/(1-Y_P) 
v = gf(-486664).sqrt()*u/X_P,-(gf(-486664).sqrt())*u/X_P
print u
print v
```

on the [Sage Cell server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You operations have to be modulo $p$ where $p=2^{255}-19$ because you are working in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Answer (score 2):

Note you're doing direct division instead of modular inverse.

Since there is **no division in elliptic curve arithmetic**, you need to do mod inverse. `pow` function could be used as a helper here; it takes third argument as modulus:

```
>>> P = 2 ** 255 - 19
>>> X = 15112221349535400772501151409588531511454012693041857206046113283949847762202
>>> Y = 46316835694926478169428394003475163141307993866256225615783033603165251855960
>>> mod_inverse = lambda x: pow(x, P - 2, P)
>>> # we are replacing `/ 1 - Y` with `* inverse(1 - Y)`
>>> ((1 + Y) * mod_inverse(1 - Y)) % P
9
```